# Cannot Install Locate Command

Tags: command-line, firefox

I recently decided to try Linux (Ubuntu 22.04), but I'm having a lot of difficulty even with what seems to be the most basic and trivial tasks.

Right now, I'm trying to install the command `locate`.  Online research suggests `sudo apt install mlocate` should do it.  When I run that command in the terminal I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to parse package file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1).
```

(as an aside, I did uninstall the snap version of Firefox, installed the snap version of Chromium, and then tried to install the deb version of Firefox, a task in which I was not successful, so I uninstalled Firefox from the terminal, and now although I believe I have eliminated Firefox from Ubuntu, I continue to get this `E: Unable to parse package file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1)` frequently, regardless of the command I use.

But, back to `locate`.

Now that I've done `sudo apt install mlocate`, when I type `locate skypeforlinux.desktop` I get this:

```
Command 'locate' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install plocate.
```

Ok.  So, then I try `sudo apt install plocate` and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to parse package file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1).
```

So then I try again, `locate skypeforlinux.desktop`, and I get this:

```
Command 'locate' not found, but can be installed with:
Sudo apt install plocate.
```

Which, obviously, is what I just did...

I've also tried `mlocate skypeforlinux.desktop` and `plocate skypeforlinux.desktop` and those don't work either.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Bonus points for helping me to understand/remove this constant `E: Unable to parse package file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1)` message.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1)`?  Whatever your preferences file is has some kind of misconfiguration in it and is not properly formatted for parsing by apt.

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong when you tried to install the deb version of firefox. The culprit is the broken file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox`. Due to this somehow misconfigured file you couldn't install firefox as a deb package, furthermore you can't install any other package. Any attempt to install a package is aborted with the error message `E: Unable to parse package file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox (1)`.

Remove the broken file from your system with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

After doing that, you will be able to install the `locate` package with

```
sudo apt install plocate
```